# How to add tags after a wp_insert_post() with get_meta_tags()

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to create or assign tags to a post by extracting keywords from a website with `get_meta_tags()` but I can't do it successfully.

for example, youtube has these meta keywords: **video, sharing, camera phone, video phone, free, upload**

```
    $postarr = array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_author' => $post_author_id,
                'post_content' => $post_content,
                'post_title' => $post_title,
                'post_excerpt' => $post_excerpt,
                'post_status' => $post_status,
                'post_type' => $post_type
                
            );

 $insert_update_post_id = wp_insert_post( $postarr );
            
            $sitio =$form_data['_custom_field|link'];
            
            $tags = get_meta_tags('https://www.youtube.com/');

wp_set_post_terms( $insert_update_post_id, $post_assign_terms, $tags['keywords'] );
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No all sites are happy with requests by what they think are "bots", so youtube might simply be blocking you here, and not serve you the content it otherwise would to a normal browser.